# Use of "adorn" as a verb

Tags: verbs

Interested in hearing some thoughts on the word "adorn." Someone I'm working with recently used it like this:

"They all adorn fancy masks for the party."

They mean it is in: "They all wear fancy masks for the party."

I know you could (excusing the passive voice) say something like, "Each person at the party was adorned by a fancy mask."

Or "Fancy masks adorned each person."

But can you say "They adorn fancy masks."?

Comment: I see you are apologising for using the passive voice. Contrary to the views of the anti-passive-voice clique there is nothing inherently  wrong with the passive voice. It can, and has been, over-used but that is a separate issue,

Comment: I think someone believes that's how you spell _don_, meaning put on and wear clothing.

Answer (score 5):

Your coworker is confusing *adorn* with *don*:

*They all don fancy masks for the party.*

> **don**<sup>2</sup>
>  transitive verb
>  <sub>[with object]</sub>
>
> Put on (an item of clothing)
>  <sub>‘in the locker room the players
> donned their football jerseys’</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [Lexico —
> *don*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/don)</sub>

So, they all put on masks for the party. Compare:

*They all adorn fancy masks for the party.*

> **adorn transitive verb**
>  <sub>[with object]</sub>
>
> Make more beautiful or attractive.
> <sub>‘pictures and prints adorned
> his walls’</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [Lexico —
> *adorn*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/adorn)</sub>

There, they all—for example—put sequins on masks for the party.

If you need to use *adorn* and you need the people in the masks, you can try the past participle adjective use:

> *They are adorned with fancy masks for the party.*

Or, less likely, the passive voice:

> *They are adorned by fancy masks for the party.*

Or, unlikely, the active voice:

> *Fancy masks adorn them for the party.*

Comment: Or with 'attired themselves with ...'.

Answer (score 1):

Since *adorn* is transitive and the object is *masks*, that sentence would only make sense if it meant that the party-goers were somehow decorating their own masks.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. It makes it seem like they're decorating rather than wearing.

Comment: With "adorned", however, I see both "adorned by" and "adorned with" in Google Books, e.g., "a sacred tree adorned *by* amulets" and "a tree adorned *with* multicolored ribbons." *With* is more frequent in the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adorned+by%2Cadorned+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadorned%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadorned%20with%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @DjinTonic The example "adorned by amulets" is still transitive, with the amulets doing the adorning of the tree, just by being there. If that is applied to the OP example, the people would be attached to the masks as adornments.

Comment: In "The tree was adorned with amulets by the islanders," the islanders did the adorning. In "The tree was adorned/The tree was adorned by amulets" we don't know who did  doing the adorning, but the amulets didn't. I think "The tree was adorned by amulets by the islanders" is grammatical.

Comment: I disagree. In "the tree was adorned by amulets" (which is grammatical), the amulets did the adorning. It means the same thing as "amulets adorned the tree". In a different use, *the islanders adorned the tree [with amulets]*, the islanders did the adorning by means of amulets, after which the amulets adorned the tree. They are all transitive meanings of adorn. Your last sentence may be grammatical, but I would not repeat *by* in two different senses the way you have.